# Using Xbee java API

Tags: xbee, java

I am trying to turn Xbee's pin on and off with a diffrent xbee(XB24-ZB) by using the [java api](https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/) library.

This is my system cunfig:
1.XBEE - Routher API (COM7)
2.XBEE - Coordinator API (COM17)

Two of them are with the same ID.
I am using the exmaple code:

```
XBee xbee = new XBee();
xbee.open("COM17", 9600);

// this is the Serial High (SH) + Serial Low (SL) of the remote XBee                    
XBeeAddress64 addr64 = new XBeeAddress64("00 13 A2 00 40 A7 3E 7E");

// Turn on DIO0 (Pin 20)
RemoteAtRequest request = new RemoteAtRequest(addr64, "D0", new int[XBeePin.Capability.DIGITAL_OUTPUT_HIGH.getValue()]);

xbee.sendAsynchronous(request);

RemoteAtResponse response = (RemoteAtResponse) xbee.getResponse();

if (response.isOk()) {
    System.out.println("Successfully turned on DIO0");
} else {
    System.out.println("Attempt to turn on DIO0 failed.  Status: " + response.getStatus());
}

// shutdown the serial port and associated threads
xbee.close();
```

When I run this block of code the DI0 on xbee #1 does change, but to 0(disabled) and not to 5.
I also get this error:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.rapplogic.xbee.api.InputStreamThread).
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.rapplogic.xbee.api.InputStreamThread).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

The "AP" is set to 2 as said and the response I get is good.
So what am I missing here?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these imports:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

Add this line to you class:

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

And, inside the main(), put this line beginning:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

I took it from the code examples inside the API src folder, and with it my programs are running just fine.